# Unwanted UITextField reloading after cancel on camera view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have an `UIActionSheet` that implements `clickedbuttonAtIndex:`

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    imagePickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];

    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:

            imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

            break;
        case 1:

            imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

            break;
     }
}
```

where option **1** pulls up the Camera and option **2** pulls up the user's photo library. The problem is that when you hit 'Cancel' on the camera, going back to the original view, it reloads two `UITextFields` which lie in a `UITableViewCell` in the main table view. I need to not see that reload. This activity does not happen when hitting 'Cancel' on the photo library view.

I have tried using this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

-But this did not preload the `UITextFields`

Why is the cancel button reloading these UITextFields and what can I do to stop this?

~Thanks, Chisx

Comment: Hi Chisx is image picker cancel delegate is also implemented - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker ?

Comment: Yeah.. very possible, I think I could maybe check that in the docs, but I'm not sure that will tell me why the UITextFields are reloading